# How to retrieve real time video stream(from web camera) from flash media server in a browser?

Tags: flash, webcam, flash-media-server

Or say,

How does the *url* of FMS real time video stream look like? I guess it shouldn't be like `http://domain.name/f.flv`, then how is it like?

Answer (score 0):

I believe for realtime video there is no URL for the stream.  There should be a URL for the FMS application instance you need to connect to, and after you connect you'd have to start playing the stream over that connection, using [NetStream.play()](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/NetStream.html).  You'd need to use the same stream name that was used by whatever is publishing the stream.

Comment: Is it possible to modify FMS so that it can generate a url for the stream ?